# How to Find a Folder's contents and delete them in another Folder?

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file

I'm trying to create a program that can have a whitelist folder and a target folder. The whitelist folder tells the program what to delete in the target folder.

For example lets say I have FOLDER1 and FOLDER2
FOLDER1 has a Text document named "Hi"
FOLDER2 has 2 Text documents, one named "Hi" (the same text document) and another named "Hello"

I want the program to see that FOLDER1 one has a whitelist for "Hi" and delete it from FOLDER2.

Could anyone help?!

I've already tried putting all of FOLDER1's contents in a string variable and deleting it from FOLDER2. And I've tried simply just doing Del FOLDER1 FOLDER2.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH_LIST=
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION   

FOR /r C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\FOLDER1 %%X IN (.svn) DO (
    ECHO %%X
    SET PATH_LIST=!PATH_LIST! "%%X"
)

ENDLOCAL

RD /s /q %PATH_LIST%
Pause
```

that did absolutely nothing and I couldn't even see what it did because the CMD decided not to paused whilst being specifically told to.

Comment: Your current code does not even attempt to delete any files, just attempts to `r`emove `d`irectory... maybe just `cd /d FOLDER1 & for %%i in (*.svn) do if exist "FOLDER2\%%~i" del "FOLDER2\%%~i"` if you want to recursively search through sub-folders it needs to change quite a bit though.

Comment: I'd prefer to cater for all files, this version also removes matching filenames within `FOLDER2` and all of its subdirectories: `@For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D "FOLDER1" 2^>NUL') Do @Del /A/F/S "FOLDER2\%%A" 2>NUL`

Comment: Thank you: very useful.

Comment: I just tried it and thank you so much it actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

The answer if your trying to do what I'm doing, was provided by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523740/how-to-find-a-folders-contents-and-delete-them-in-another-folder#comment103374398_58523740):

```bat
@For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D "FOLDER1" 2^>NUL') Do @Del /A/F/S "FOLDER2\%%A" 2>NUL
```